# monaca localkit に関して

Tags: monaca, iphone, cordova, network

Monacaでローカル開発をする為の設定をしています。
こちらのURL(http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/manual/localkit/monaca_localkit_index/)の情報を参考にlocal kitをインストールしたのですが、同一の無線NW上にあるiPhoneがローカル開発PCから認識できません。
またiPhoneからローカル開発PCの認識もできません。IPアドレスを直接打って8000番ポートを指定してみても、「未定義のローカルコンピュータ。」というエラーメッセージが表示されます。

PCからiPhoneへのping疎通、PCの8000番ポートが空いている事は確認済です。
他に何か設定が必要なものがございましたら、教えていただけませんでしょうか。

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

最近Monacaを触りはじめました。私も同じ現象で未だにlocalkitをiPhoneから認識しない問題は解消できていません。

質問への直接の回答ではないのですが、Monaca Cli経由で`monaca livesync`するとiPhoneから同じWi-Fi上のMacを認識してくれました。

http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/manual/development/monaca_cli/